# MSMQ: Receiving both positive & negative acknowledgments for delivery of a message

Tags: https, msmq

I have a simple C# application that sends a message via MSMQ to a remote server over HTTPS.
I have specified a TimeToReachQueue value for the message, and an administration queue so I can receive positive or negative acknowledgments regarding delivery of the message (I specified "FullReachQueue" as the AcknowledgeType.)
About 10 seconds after I send the message, I get a message in my local administration queue saying "The message reached the queue." However, after the TimeToReachQueue interval expires--be it 30 seconds or 5 minutes-- I get a second message saying "The time-to-reach-queue has elapsed."
Every reference to the "TimeToReachQueue" interval I can find says you will only get a negative acknowledgment if the message didn't reach the queue within the specified interval.

When I check the remote server's queue, the message is actually in the destination queue, so how can I receive messages saying both that it did and didn't arrive?

Answer (score 1):

Are there any outgoing queues on the remote server pointing back to the original sending machine that contain ack messages of any kind?

Comment: Yes--when I send a message, the remote server creates 2 outgoing queues. One is http ://sendingserver/adminqueue, and the state is "connected", but there are 0 messages. The other is https ://sendingserver/adminqueue?SenderStream=LOTS_OF_STUFF, and has 1 "QM Ordering ACK" message, but its status is "waiting to connect" and then it goes inactive.

Comment: There you go, then. MSMQ uses acks for both internal and user-specified purposes. The internal acks aren't getting back home, causing the TTRQ to timeout. The second outgoing queue is pointing at an HTTPS version of the admin address. I assume the sendingserver has no SSL certificate setup so that's failing. Never seen that before but then I have had very little experience with MSMQ over SSL.

Comment: The sending server does have a valid, trusted certificate. Our best guess now is that it's a NAT issue.

Comment: NAT issue? Wouldn't that stop the http ://sendingserver/adminqueue from working too? Quick test - can you browse to httpS://sendingserver/adminqueue from the remote server using IE (or similar)?